# Cannot connect to aws rds Postgresql using master password and username but pgAdmin works

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I Cannot connect to AWS rds Postgresql using master password and username but pgAdmin connection with the certificate works perfectly.

My website, when it tries to connect to the database, says:

```
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I ssh into my ec2 instance of the Elastic Beanstalk and it gives me the following error when I am trying to connect to the rds:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "user"
FATAL:  pg_hba.conf rejects connection for host "111.11.1.11", user "user", database "database", SSL off
```

The command I use to connect is this:

```
psql --host=rds_endpoint --port=5432 --username=user --password --dbname=database
```

I changed the master password and still, it does not work.

Again, If I use pgAdming with ssl certificate and that token that it generates, the connection is successful and I have full access to the database.

Also, the command

```
nc -zv rds_endpoint 5432
```

gives the successfull result:

```
Ncat: Connected to 111.11.11.11:5432.
```

The master username is and password does not contain any special character.

```
Master username: user
```

Comment: Is it possible that the password contains special characters? Try escaping them. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-connect.html#id-1.7.3.8.3.6

Comment: PAM is the tech used to implement IAM authentication. Are you sure the user you are connecting as is really the master user?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue when the password contained special characters. I need to escape them in the connection URL used in psql

Percent-encoding may be used to include symbols with special meaning in any of the URI parts, e.g., replace = with %3D.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/libpq-connect.html#id-1.7.3.8.3.6